# Move element in array in time log(n)

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I have two arrays name[i] and signal[i] , both size n.

```
Tom  Tim  Kate  Jim
0    1     1    0
```

where names are stored in array name with some order and each name with 0 or 1 value.

I want to move all names with 0 value to the left of the array while those with 1 to the right, and the order don't change. therefore the result looks like

```
Tom   Jim   Tim   Kate
0      0     1     1
```

The key is how to achieve it with n CPU in time log(n) please?

Comment: Perform a [parallel prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Parallel_algorithm) on the number of zeros in the list.   This can be done by n processors in O(log(n)) time. Now each processor knows the number of zeros, z_i, to their left; if their signal is a zero, they store their name in new_name[z_i] and a zero in new_signal[z_i].  Similarly with the ones data (but you'll also need the total number of zeros).

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I have one question. What does "to their left" mean in your answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can split the names in two arrays of size n according to the signal value. And then use an algorithm similar of "Parallel Reduction" to gather your names inside each arrays and then collapse the two arrays in one.

Each threads read the name associated to its thread's number. If the name's signal is a 0 its add the name in the name_0[thread_id], similar things with signal equal to 1. So you have 2 ordered arrays, in the first all the signal 0 and in the second all the signal 1. So you "just" have to collapse these 2 arrays (inspire you of "Parallel Reduction algorithm" ?).

That's the most simple/parallel-processing algorithm that I see.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible, just figuring out which one's are zero and which ones are one will take O(n) time because you have to look at each one.

With n cores, you can have each core look at a different element, then they look to their neighbour and the left one accepts all the ones with zeros and the odd one accepts the ones have a one.  The even indexed cores repeat this with their even indexed neighbours, and so on...

After O(log n) of these operations, the left most core will have all the items with a zero and the rightmost will have all the items with a one.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What if I have n CPU and run it in parallel